# Datatables for Visual Studio 2012 MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a datatable that is build up in JQuery. The declaration looks like:

```
oTable =
    $('#rules-datatable').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": [0], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [1], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [2], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [3], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [4], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [5], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [6], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [7], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [8], "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mDataProp": [9], "sWidth": "10%" }
    ],
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetAllCapturedRules")',
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.toString().indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) {
            // This fixes the IE8 overflow issue. Style is added after the datatable has been drawn.
            $('#main').addClass('overflow-fix');
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to get the values of the selected row after a click event, but it doesn't seem to work. My click event look as follows:

```
oTable.click(function () {
    var anSelected = oTable.$('tr.row_selected');
    if (anSelected.length == 0) {
        alert('Please make a selection');
    } else {
        // Get data from the selected row                    
    }
}
```

On the click event it always displays 'Please make a selection', so it never gets the value of the selected row. Can someone please explain why, and how to work around this? I am using datables v 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The following will add the click event to each table row

```
oTable.$("tr").on("click", function(){
    //TR that was clicked, you can now get the information from rowClicked
    var rowClicked = $(this);        
});
```

Is this what you are looking for?